# What is wrong with this MySQL query? In the output it just shows the column name

Tags: mysql

**This question is from strata scratch**: Write a query that calculates the difference between the highest salaries found in the marketing and engineering departments. Output just the absolute difference in salaries.

Tables: db_employee, db_dept

Code:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(max_eng_salary) - MAX(max_mark_salary) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      department_id AS dept_id, 
      MAX(salary) as max_eng_salary 
    FROM 
      db_employee 
    WHERE 
      department_id = "1"
  ) AS eng_salary 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      department_id AS dept_id, 
      MAX(salary) AS max_mark_salary 
    FROM 
      db_employee 
    WHERE 
      department_id = "4"
  ) AS mark_salary ON eng_salary.dept_id = mark_salary.dept_id;
```

Comment: Edit your question to define exactly what "not correct" means. eg wrong answer, error message, something else.

Comment: btw, you don't need to select `dept_id` in your subqueries; only `MAX(salary)` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries:

```
select abs(
  (select max(salary) from db_employee where department_id = '1') -
  (select max(salary) from db_employee where department_id = '4')
)
```